# Drain pipe blocking shower installation

Tags: plumbing

I'm in the process of removing an old bathtub/shower and replacing it with a walk-in shower.  The problem is that a 1 1/2" drain pipe that was once covered by the tub is now eating into where my new shower floor/walls will be.  I'd like to redirect it through the bottom plate of the wall, but the wall is flush with a floor joist that's already been notched and strapped.  For some reason there's also already an unoccupied notch in the bottom plate.

Here are some pictures:

[image: View of the shower area]

[image: Close-up of the trespassing pipe]

[image: Pipe as it goes into beam]

What are my options?

Comment: Seems like that bend should've been reversed, passing through the notch in the plate. Someone got lazy. Do you have access to the floor cavity on the other side of the wall?

Answer (score 2):

I would add another framed wall, adjacent to the one that's there, that's just 3'0" high (except for where the drain pipe runs to the ceiling).  This would create an in-shower ledge that's 4" deep...great place to put shampoo bottles, etc.  One could also create a between-stud nooks above the in-shower ledge.  This idea, of course, would have me bring the shower forward to retain dimensions.

Comment: Good idea. You can either do this or redo the plumbing in this area.